# viewing guzzle post request

Tags: php, xml, api, guzzle

i would like to see the post request packet before i send it as there is an error in the req and a the api is a general descript 500
error so i cant tell where y request is failing. i mnow the xml is formatted wrong as it works on postman from chrome.

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'base_uri' => 'https://elstestserver.endicia.com',
        ]);
$xml = 'changePassPhraseRequestXML=<ChangePassPhraseRequest>  <RequesterID>lxxx</RequesterID><RequestID>1263055835</RequestID><CertifiedIntermediary><AccountID>lxxx</AccountID><PassPhrase>dfdsfsd</PassPhrase></CertifiedIntermediary><NewPassPhrase>fdfdsfdsfs</NewPassPhrase></ChangePassPhraseRequest>';

    $data = array("ChangePassPhraseXML" => $xml);

  $response = $client->post("/LabelService/EwsLabelService.asmx/ChangePassPhraseXML", [
'form_params'    => $data
]);
```

this request works in postman for chrome the heres a working example of the xml

```
changePassPhraseRequestXML=<ChangePassPhraseRequest><RequesterID>lxxx</RequesterID><RequestID>1263055835</RequestID><CertifiedIntermediary><AccountID>lxxx</AccountID><PassPhrase>dfdsfsd</PassPhrase></CertifiedIntermediary><NewPassPhrase>fdsfdsfds</NewPassPhrase></ChangePassPhraseRequest>
```

Comment: You would be looking for the debug request option.  If you set it to true within the client's instantiation all requests made by the client will output the request to php://stdout  .  For reference: http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/request-options.html#debug

Answer (score 0):

Use [Logger middleware](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Middleware.php#L185)

[About middlewares for guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/handlers-and-middleware.html)

Also, 500 error is server fail, not yours.